# Simple secured SFTP tunnel?

Tags: security, sftp, tunnel, winscp, netcat

I'd like to setup an sftp tunnel so that I can connect to an IP-secured SFTP server through a gateway computer from anywhere, and download the files to anywhere.

I was thinking of using a combination with netcat, having it listen to either WinSCP or PuTTY sFTP (doesn't matter which). Not sure how I would download the files to the connecting computer though.  I would like the tunnel to be secured, preferably, with a username/password.

I'm open to using alternative software but I'm looking for unintrusive, simple command line stuff because I don't want to install a lot on this computer.

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to know what operating systems you are running on both the SFTP and gateway machines.

Comment: Windows on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install OpenSSH server and Netcat on the gateway and then it becomes a matter of [using `ProxyCommand` properly](https://serverfault.com/search?q=+%2Bnc+%2Bproxycommand).